# obexd - Receive files error

Tags: bluetooth, bluez

I am facing the below error while trying to receive files via bluetooth. The pairing is successful and sending files from the board to the phone is also successful. But receiving files from phone to board is showing the below error.

```
obexd[546]: disconnected: Unicode conversion failed: Conversion from character set “UTF-16BE” to “UTF-8” is not supported
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem and I resolve it just now.

In my case I had not set the `copy gconv libraries` option in the Linaro external toolchain options of my buildroot distribution. I set it and now all works fine.